# The total number of all different integers in all partitions of n with smallest part $\geq 2$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I want to show that the total number of all different integers in all partitions of $n$ with smallest part $ \geq 2$ is $p(n-2)$.

Example: partitions of $7$ with smallest part $ \geq 2$ are (7), (5,2), (4,3), (3, 2, 2). Let’s count distinct parts in each, so we get respectively 1 + 2 + 2  + 2 = 7 = p(7 - 2) = p(5).

Could you give any reference to the proof of that fact? Or maybe some hints to prove it in laconic way?

Comment: You can prove this associating to each partition [its conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Conjugate_and_self-conjugate_partitions)

Comment: @NDB I am not sure how conjugates can help there

Comment: This fact seems a little surprising. I am voting to reopen.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451202/number-of-partitions-of-n-and-number-of-different-integers-in-1-avoiding-parti

Comment: The partition function [OEIS A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041) entry states "From Peter Bala, Dec 23 2013: (Start) a(n-1) = Sum_{parts k in all partitions of n} mu(k), where mu(k) is the arithmetical Möbius function (see A008683). Let P(2,n) denote the set of partitions of n into parts k >= 2. Then a(n-2) = -Sum_{parts k in all partitions in P(2,n)} mu(k)."

Comment: @SeanEberhard Oh, great. Someone also discovered this fact after four days, how interesting. There are good answers though.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of answering this question, answers are given over at https://mathoverflow.net/q/451202/20598.